# C# Unity3D tank turret pointed to a wrong way

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a newbie in Unity3D and start to make a tank game, but I don't know what wrong with my code.

The tank game used 3rd person camera, I want the turret points to the crosshair. I use the camera rotation to control the turret, so when player rotates the camera, the turret will point to the same way, but somehow the turret is not pointing the correct direction.

```
private void turretMove()
    {
        Quaternion m_CamRotateX = Quaternion.Euler(0, m_Cam.GetComponent<CameraControl>().m_CamX, 0);
        m_turret.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(m_turret.transform.localRotation, m_CamRotateX, m_turretSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

This camera script is from internet

```
namespace Complete
{
public class CameraControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float distance = 5.0f;
    public float xSpeed = 120.0f;
    public float ySpeed = 120.0f;
    public float m_baseDist = 10f;

    public float yMinLimit = -20f;
    public float yMaxLimit = 80f;

    public float distanceMin = 5f;
    public float distanceMax = 15f;

    private Rigidbody rigidbody;

    public float m_CamX = 0.0f;
    public float m_CamY = 0.0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Vector3 angles = transform.eulerAngles;
        m_CamX = angles.y;
        m_CamY = angles.x;

        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        // Make the rigid body not change rotation
        if (rigidbody != null)
        {
            rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
        }
    }

    public void LateUpdate()
    {
            m_CamX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * distance * 0.02f;
            m_CamY -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02f;
            m_CamY = ClampAngle(m_CamY, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);

            Quaternion m_CamRotate = Quaternion.Euler(m_CamY, m_CamX, 0);

            distance = Mathf.Clamp(distance - m_baseDist * 5, distanceMin, distanceMax);

            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Linecast(target.position, transform.position, out hit))
            {
                distance -= hit.distance;
            }
            Vector3 negDistance = new Vector3(0.0f, 2.0f, -distance);
            Vector3 position = m_CamRotate * negDistance + target.position;

            transform.rotation = m_CamRotate;
            transform.position = position;
    }

    public static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
    {
        if (angle < -360f)
            angle += 360f;
        if (angle > 360f)
            angle -= 360f;
        return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So, where is it pointing instead?

Comment: Problem almost can be solved. how to apply time.deltatime in this code? "m_turret.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0,newOff.y, 0);"